# Handle NULL xml nodes in Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

How can I access the body and/or avoid error of NULL values in xml nodes in mule data weave.

Consider this is my node:

```xml
<catalog>
    <product product-id="D158413" mode="delete"/>
    <product product-id="556204380">
    <ean>5014414203648</ean>
    <display-name>Double duvet cover</display-name>
    <long-description>Line</long-description>
    <online-flag>true</online-flag>
    <available-flag>true</available-flag>
    <searchable-flag>true</searchable-flag>
    <tax-class-id>default</tax-class-id>
    <brand>Linea</brand>
    <manufacturer-name>Linea</manufacturer-name>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Care Instructions">Machine</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Colour">Pink</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Finish">Plain</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Guarantee">N/A</custom-attribute>
    </product>  
</catalog>
```

My Dataweave Code is :

```java
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/xml
%output application/java 
---
(payload.catalog.*product default []) map  {
    CatalogDetails:{
            CatalogId:payload.catalog.@catalog-id
    },
    ProdDetails:{
                product-id:$.@product-id,
                mode:$.@mode,
                ean:$.ean,
                upc:$.upc,
                min-order-quantity:$.min-order-quantity,    
                display-name:$.display-name,
                short-description:$.short-description
    },
CustValues: { (
            ($.custom-attributes.*custom-attribute default []) map {      
                (sellByUnitVal: $)  when ($.@attribute-id) == "sellByUnit" ,
                (VOLUMEVal: $) when ($.@attribute-id) == "VOLUME",
                (UnitMeasureVal: $) when ($.@attribute-id) == "UnitMeasure"
             } 
        ) }
   }
```

The first Product node doesn't receive a body. I tried using default `[]` but it's not working. How can I make sure it always receives a body?

Comment: Isn't it the third product that is null? Can you show us the code you are using to read the xml nodes?

Comment: I shared my sample code.. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your XML example isn't complete and valid, missing  and upc values etc. that you are using in your DataWeave script.

Your solution is probably something like checking the sizeOf the node, and if it's 0 fill it op with a whitespace, if not execute your normal script.

If you have your complete examples that would help.

Comment: The xml is proper.. some nodes may come into incoming xml or may not. so I have to create mapping for those elements also. Product node is repeating in input xml. For demo purpose I have added only 2 products

Answer (score 0):

I have found out one way to handle the empty nodes as, we can use filter to skip the empty nodes,

```
(payload.catalog.*product default []) filter ($ !='') map { }
```

Using this we control the empty or non empty tags into the transformation.